# Semi-stable sheaves on quadric surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, hilbert-polynomials

https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2014/346126.pdf

In this paper, Stable sheaves on a smooth quadric surface with linear Hilbert bipolynomials(E. Ballico and S.Huh), I have a question.

On the right down of the page 2 of this paper,

> For every semistable 1-dimensional sheaf $F$ with $\chi_F(x, y)=mx+ny+t$, define $C_F:=\mathrm {Supp}(F)$ to be its scheme-theoretic support and then we have $C_F \in |O_Q(n, m)|$.

Question : In this sentence, how we conclude that  $C_F \in |O_Q(n, m)|$?

Comment: This should follow from Riemann-Roch. Imagine that the sheaf is a rank 1 sheaf on a curve of type $(a,b)$, use RR to compute $\chi$ of its twists, and compare. So, the only problem is to show that its rank is 1 (it could be, say, a rank 2-sheaf on a curve of type $(n/2,m/2)$, or the curve could have several components and the sheaf could have different rank on different components), but this probably follows from other assumptions in the paper.

Comment: @Sasha Thank you for the comment. However, I cannot understand your explanation since my lack of comprehension. Please explain above thing more detail.

Comment: What part of the explanation are you missing? Can you apply RR?

Comment: I know RR. But how apply RR to compute $\chi$ of its twist?

Comment: Do you know how a line bundle twist modifies the Chern character of a sheaf?

Comment: Yes, I know that.

Comment: Then substitute this into RR.

Comment: Okay. By the way, how does this computation conclude $C_F \in |O_Q(n, m)|$?

Comment: I think you will see this after performing the RR computation.